# Can not make view firstResponder in viewDidAppear method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have UIViewController and I created my custom class for its view. By the way, I redefined method "canBecomeFirstResponder" in that class so it always returns true. I want my view to become first responder when the viewDidAppear method is called. But after I go to another controller and come back my program crashes. Can not understand why does this happens. Here is some code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.firstResponder = self.view.isFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if(self.firstResponder){
        self.view!.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: @jtbandes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on becomesFirstResponder function. And it does not even reach canBecomeFirstResponder method

Comment: it crashes on view did appear ?

Comment: @Mr.T Yes in viewDidAppear method on becomesFirstResponder function

Comment: Why do you need the exclamation mark on self.view!  ?

Comment: @Darko I tried without it too... It is just attempt to do smth. In fact it does not matter.

Comment: you should share your custom class code too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906036/text-becomefirstresponder-throws-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x1

Comment: What do you want to achieve with calling becomeFirstResponder on the view object?

Comment: @Darko thank you. Your link helped me a lot. I really should not have named my property "firstResponder". When I renamed it everything worked ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link helped me a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21906038/4092466 I should not have named the property "firstResponder". When I renamed it everything worked fine.